# Edit certain variables in a file using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line, grep

Below i have the following `SES.ses` file:

```
1 VERSION_CONTROL {
2    FILE_NAME = "C:/Users/kjbaili/Documents/SWCD_TEST/SES.ses";
3    DATE = "";
4    VERSION = "1.1";
5    AUTHOR = "";
6  }
7
8  DISPLAYS {
9    DISPLAY xxx-c-vm-0120:main = {
10        COMPUTER = "xxx-C-VM-0120";
11        DISPLAY = "main";
12        ITEMS {
13            PANEL  {
14                name = "visu.pnl";
15            }
16        }
17    }
18   }
19
20   RT-HOSTS {
21    RT-HOST xxx-c-vm-0120 = {
22        COMPONENT  {
23            name = "RTE_connections_xxxxx.cmp";
24        }
25        COMPONENT  {
26            name = "xxxx.cmp";
27        }
28    }
29    RT-HOST xxx-c-agx-0003 = {
30        COMPONENT  {
31            name = "CtApxxx.cmp";
32        }
33        COMPONENT  {
34            name = "CtApxxx.cmp";
35        }
36        COMPONENT  {
37            name = "CtApxxx.cmp";
38        }
39    }
40   }
41
42   HARDWARE {
43    }
```

The user enters three Inputs to be placed in lines `2`, `9`, `21` and `29` -> `/userpath`, `DISPLAY  Node0`, `RT-HOSTS Node0`, and `RT-HOSTS Node1` accordingly.

I'm trying to edit variables in this file based on above user's input. These are : `FILE_NAME (line 2)`, `DISPLAY (line 9)`, `RT-HOSTS ( line 21 and 29)`

After doing some research i could build the following:

```
currentPath=$(pwd)/SES    

awk -v path="$currentPath" '/FILE_NAME/ {cnt++} /FILE_NAME/ && cnt==1 {lnee=gensub(/(^.*\")(.*)(\".*$)/,"\\1"path"\\3",$0);print lnee; next}1' SES.ses > SES.temp && mv -f SES.tmp SES.ses
```

This command supposes to find the first entry for `FILE_NAME` and set the variable `currentPath` to it. However i'm getting the following error:

```
    awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\"' is not a known regexp operator
mv: cannot stat 'SES.tmp': No such file or directory
```

So my question is how to solve this error and how to set the other three variables `line 9, 21 and 29`

Thank in advance and would really appriciate your help

suggested solution from @Ed Morton:

```
    awk -v filename='foo' -v display='bar' -v rthosts='some others' 'BEGIN { numRth = split(rthosts,rths) }

(filename != "") && ($1 == "FILE_NAME") { newval=filename; filename="" }
(display != "")  && ($1 == "DISPLAY")   { newval=display;   display="" }
(numRth in rths) && ($1 == "RT-HOST")   { newval=rths[++c]; delete rths[c] }

newval != "" {
    oldval = ( $2 == "=" ? $3 : $2 )
    gsub(/^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$/,"",oldval)
    pos = index($0,oldval)
    $0 = substr($0,1,pos-1) newval substr($0,pos+length(oldval))
    newval = ""
}

{ print }' SES.ses
```

output of `cat -Ev SES.ses`

```
$
VERSION_CONTROL {$
    FILE_NAME = "/c/Users/kjbaili/Documents/DO_NOT_DELETE/SES";$
    DATE = "";$
    VERSION = "1.1";$
    AUTHOR = "";$
}$
$
DISPLAYS {$
    DISPLAY d = {$
        COMPUTER = "FDT-C-VM-0120";$
        DISPLAY = "main";$
        ITEMS {$
            PANEL  {$
                name = "visu.pnl";$
            }$
        }$
    }$
}$
$
RT-HOSTS {$
    RT-HOST v = {$
        COMPONENT  {$
            name = "RTE_connections_CtCoFallbackPath.cmp";$
        }$
        COMPONENT  {$
            name = "CtGwHwpFbpCmp.cmp";$
        }$
    }$
    RT-HOST v = {$
        COMPONENT  {$
            name = "CtApHwpFbpSit.cmp";$
        }$
        COMPONENT  {$
            name = "CtApHwpFbpMpl.cmp";$
        }$
        COMPONENT  {$
            name = "CtApHwpFbpCVGen.cmp";$
        }$
    }$
}$
$
HARDWARE {$
}$
```

Comment: Try to make your question shorter. Something like "I want to change substrings in different lines with `awk`, only some have double quotes as a FS. I tried `echo '  FILE_NAME = "C:/Users/kjbaili/Documents/SWCD_TEST/SES.ses";' | awk ...` but failed. You might get an answer like `awk -v path="$PWD" '{lnee=gensub(/(^[^"]*")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1" path "\\3", 1, $0);print "x=" lnee; next}'`.

Comment: Are you trying to set RT_HOST to the same value on lines 21 and 29 or 2 different values? Are you trying to change values at specific line numbers 9, 21, and 29 or trying to change the values associated with occurrences of DISPLAY and RT_HOST which just happen to be at lines 9, 21, and 29 in this particular sample input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument to the `gensub()` function must be a count of replacement
such as `1` or `g` (global).
Would you please try instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

# user's inputs
read -p "FILE_NAME: " -r file_name
read -p "DISPLAY: " -r display
read -p "RT-HOST: " -r rt_host

awk -v file_name="$file_name" -v display="$display" -v rt_host="$rt_host" '
{
    sub(/FILE_NAME *= *\"[^"]+/, "FILE_NAME = \"" file_name)
    sub(/DISPLAY *[^:]+:/, "DISPLAY " display ":")
}
/RT-HOST / {
    if (! count++)
        sub(/RT-HOST *[^[:space:]]+ *=/, "RT-HOST " display " =")
    else
        sub(/RT-HOST *[^[:space:]]+ *=/, "RT-HOST " rt_host " =")
}
1
' SES.ses > SES.tmp && mv -f -- SES.tmp SES.ses
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works. However, the parameter `DISPLAY` should be edited until the `:main` which means :mean is fixed. Also regarding `RT_HOST`, your code set the same input value for both and in fact the fist `RT_HOST (line 20)` is different from the second `line 29` and both should be set based on user's input

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've understood you want to preserve the `:main` suffix as for the `DISPLAY` parameter
so the user does not have to type it. Regarding the `RT_HOST` input, I used the
same input for two lines because you mentioned `The user enters three Inputs` in your
question. If the user is asked for *four inputs* please update your question. BR.

Comment: Or do we use the same input for both `DISPLAY` parameter (line 9) and `RT-HOST Node1` parameter (line 21)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. yes exactly. Sorry for not making it clear in the question.I've updated my answer. So i still have three inputs. However, the DISPLAY and the first RT_HOST is the same node name/input.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I've modified my code accordingly. I hope it will meet your requirement. BR.

Comment: I tried your code. The DISPLAY parameter is not affected by the input. I mean when i enter `120` as an inpit for the DISPLAY parameter, this number must be wrtten on both line 9 & 21 except for line 9, it should be like `120:main`

Comment: If I enter `120` as an input for the DISPLAY parameter (or `display` variable), line 9 is modified to `DISPLAY 120:main = {` and line 21 is modified to `RT-HOST 120 = {`. Does not it accord with your result?

Comment: No that does not occure with my result. Only line 21 is modified as `RT-HOST 120`. Line 9  is not changing at all

Comment: Did you exactly copy&pasted my updated code? I have no idea why the same code, the same file and the same input produce the different result. One possible reason is the character after `DISPLAY`, line 9, in your file is a tab, not a whitespace.

Comment: FYI: I'm executing my script on windows. So my script is calles test.sh and it is executed on windows. Also the numbers are only for explanation and indexing breasons

Comment: Thank you for the info, but I still cannot reproduce the problem so far. It's high time for me and let me sleep on it. BR.

Comment: I found something and in fact , it returns the follwing warning when i enter all inputs awk: `cmd. line:3: warning: regexp escape sequence `\"' is not a known regexp operator`

Comment: I found out the problem. Yes you'rewrite some spacing had to be removed. Thank you alot. you're really a gold mine

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Would be happy if you could vote up my question

Comment: Good to know the problem has been solved. Thanks a lot for your patience and efforts. BR.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the warning (not error) message `escape sequence '\"' is not a known regexp operator` because `"` isn't a regexp metachar, it's just a plain old literal char like `x`, but in your regexp `(^.*\")(.*)(\".*$)` you've written `\"` so either:

1. you're trying to escape `"` when it doesn't need to be escaped
   or,
2. you're trying to include a literal `\` in your regexp but
   you'd need to escape it as `\\` to do that.

So either way something is wrong with your regexp so awk is warning you about it.

I THINK this is probably what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { numRth = split(rthosts,rths) }

(filename != "") && ($1 == "FILE_NAME") { newval=filename; filename="" }
(display != "")  && ($1 == "DISPLAY")   { newval=display;   display="" }
(numRth in rths) && ($1 == "RT-HOST")   { newval=rths[++c]; delete rths[c] }

newval != "" {
    oldval = ( $2 == "=" ? $3 : $2 )
    gsub(/^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$/,"",oldval)
    pos = index($0,oldval)
    $0 = substr($0,1,pos-1) newval substr($0,pos+length(oldval))
    newval = ""
}

{ print }
```

```
$ awk -v filename='foo' -v display='bar' -v rthosts='some others' -f tst.awk file
VERSION_CONTROL {
   FILE_NAME = "foo";
   DATE = "";
   VERSION = "1.1";
   AUTHOR = "";
 }

 DISPLAYS {
   DISPLAY bar = {
       COMPUTER = "xxx-C-VM-0120";
       DISPLAY = "main";
       ITEMS {
           PANEL  {
               name = "visu.pnl";
           }
       }
   }
  }

  RT-HOSTS {
   RT-HOST some = {
       COMPONENT  {
           name = "RTE_connections_xxxxx.cmp";
       }
       COMPONENT  {
           name = "xxxx.cmp";
       }
   }
   RT-HOST others = {
       COMPONENT  {
           name = "CtApxxx.cmp";
       }
       COMPONENT  {
           name = "CtApxxx.cmp";
       }
       COMPONENT  {
           name = "CtApxxx.cmp";
       }
   }
  }

  HARDWARE {
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your output seems exactly what i'm trying to do. However, i can't get it worl :). I mean all i have a bash file (comtaining the script) and a. SES.ses file and the bash file should do the edits in the SES.ses file when this bash file is executed

Comment: You just need to call awk exactly like I show in my answer but replace`-f tst.awk` with `'...the contents of tst.awk in my answer...'` so in your shell script you'll have `awk -v filename='foo' -v display='bar' -v rthosts='some others' 'BEGIN ... { print }' SES.ses`. Replace the hard-coded strings with shell variables or positional parameters as you like.

Comment: Sorry i mistakenlly deleted my comment. So i just fired `awk -v filename='foo' -v display='bar' -v rthosts='some others' 'BEGIN ... { print }' SES.ses` and i does nothing.

Comment: Either the input you're running it on doesn't look like the input you provided or you're doing something wrong when you copy/paste the script. Until you edit your question to show what you're doing I won't be able to help you debug it. Add this to the bottom of your question by the way - don't change anything already in your question.

Comment: Please also add the output of `cat -Ev SES.ses` so we can make sure it's not empty, etc.

Comment: OK, I looked at what you added to your question and it is utterly, 100% impossible for that script to produce no output when run on that input file. See the `{ print }` at the end of the script? That's a directive to unconditionally print the current input line - the ONLY ways it can not print anything is if the input file is empty or unreadable (which it isn't) or if the script contains a syntax error or `exit` or `next` or `nextfile` before it (which it doesn't).

Comment: What happens if you run `awk '{print}' SES.ses` - does that produce any output?

Comment: yes it produces the content of the SES.ses file which seen in the question

Comment: OK, and when you run my script - are you saying the script hangs and doesn't finish and you have to interrupt it, or that it finishes but produces no output?

Comment: no it does't hangs or wait for an interrupt. a small shell window pops up pops upand  closes.

Comment: My awk script doesn't open up any windows, it just reads text in and writes text out, Are you doing something more than just running `awk ... SES.ses` at the command line, e.g. running it from a shell script that does a bunch of other stuff or running it from some kind of IDE or editor?

Comment: No i'm not doing anything. I don't know whay to be honest, however i believe this is irrelevant as this windows always opens when i executes a bash script. May i asked: have you're tryied it locally ? i mean saving the content posted in the question as an SES.ses file and executed your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232785/discussion-between-ed-morton-and-zang322).

Answer (score 0):

If [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html) is available/acceptable.

This should show the replacement.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file_name=foobar
display=barmore
rt_host=quxfux

ed -s SES.ses <<-EOF
  2,/FILE_NAME/s/".\{1,\}"/"$file_name"/
  9s|^\([[:blank:]]*DISPLAY\).\{1,\}\(=[[:blank:]]*{\$\)|\1 $display \2|
  21,29s|^\([[:blank:]]*RT-HOST\).\{1,\}\(=[[:blank:]]*{\$\)|\1 $rt_host \2|
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

Just like what *@tshiono* did using the builtin `read` to get the *user's input*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# user's inputs
read -p "FILE_NAME: " file_name
read -p "DISPLAY: " display
read -p "RT-HOST: " rt_host

ed -s SES.ses <<-EOF
  2,/FILE_NAME/s/".\{1,\}"/"$file_name"/
  9s|^\([[:blank:]]*DISPLAY\).\{1,\}\(=[[:blank:]]*{\$\)|\1 $display \2|
  21,29s|^\([[:blank:]]*RT-HOST\).\{1,\}\(=[[:blank:]]*{\$\)|\1 $rt_host \2|
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

The `,p` is there just show what is the output of the newly edited buffer, remove it to silence the output.

Change `Q` to `w` to edit the *file-inplace*